# Arguing from something not meeting the definition using an theorem.

Tags: logic

Theorem

Let $f(\mathbf{x} \mid \theta)$ be the pmf or pdf of a sample $\mathbf{X}$. Suppose there exists a function $T(\mathbf{x})$ such that, for every two sample points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, the ratio $f(\mathbf{x} \mid \theta) / f(\mathbf{y} \mid \theta)$ is constant as a function of $\theta$ if and only if $T(\mathbf{x})=T(\mathbf{y})$. Then $T(\mathbf{X})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Bad solution:

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote two sample points, the ratio of densities is:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{f(x|\theta)}{f(y|\theta)} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\theta}{x_i^{\theta+1}} \frac{y_i^{\theta+1}}{\theta} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{y_i^{\theta+1}}{x_i^{\theta+1}} = ( \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i})^{\theta+1}
\end{equation}
The ratio will be not constant as a function of $\theta$ even if $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i = \prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i$. Thus $\hat{x}$ is not a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Problem:
I am trying to understand by means of logical similes where the error is. He sees that the problem is that the assumptions are not fulfilled and tries to use this theorem. I understand that my reasoning would be correct if the theorem were iff?

Logic symbols:

$$ (a \iff b ) \implies c $$

Bad solution
$$ \neg (a \iff b)  \implies \neg c $$
would be correct if the theorem were iff?

Comment: The theorem says: suppose we have ... a condition. If so (if the condition is satisfied), then we can conclude that $T(X)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic... Thus, we have $P \to Q$. If you were not able to prove $P$, then you are not entitled to conclude that $Q$.

Comment: Having not proved $Q$, does not mean that not-$Q$ holds...

Comment: If instead we read the statement above as a definition of "minimal sufficient statistic", then you are right: definitions need **iff**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem can be represented in propositional form as

$$(A \leftrightarrow B ) \rightarrow C$$

One may try a proof by contraposition, that is, to demonstrate that

$$\neg C\rightarrow\neg (A \leftrightarrow B)$$

Hence,

$$\neg C\rightarrow ((\neg A \wedge B) \vee (A \wedge \neg B))$$

Let us give more structure to the propositional representation we have begun with and consider the following expression in second-order logic (quasi-formal; the details to be supplied according to due statistical theoretical context)

$\exists T\{[\forall\mathbf{x}\forall\mathbf{y}\,(h(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \theta)$ is constant as a function of $\theta)$ $\leftrightarrow \forall\mathbf{x}\forall\mathbf{y}\,(T(\mathbf{x})=T(\mathbf{y}))]$$\rightarrow [T(\mathbf{X})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta]\}$

That allows us to see the proposition $B$ that has to be demonstrated in conjunction with $\neg A$, which may prove to be a tedious task.